# How to make mail() work on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, email, ubuntu-8.10

I have a new install of Ubuntu and trying to use the php's mail() function.
The function fails, I guess I am missing a package or two in my installation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you configured the mail function in your php.ini ?

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t    
or
sendmail_path = /usr/lib/sendmail -i -t
```

Comment: that was part of the answer, I had to install it too:
sudo apt-get install sendmail-bin
But it putted me on the right track. Tnx.